# Selinux stoping PhantomJs with Permission Denied Laravel Application on Fedora

Tags: php, laravel, phantomjs, fedora, selinux

I'm using fireguard to create pdf at my laravel application , but on fedora if I execute the command `setenforce 0` ,it runs just fine as expected. But if I turn selinux on with `setenforce 1` , it gives me the message :

> PhantomJS: sh: /var/www/html/.../vendor/bin/phantomjs: Permission
>   denied.

The `audit.log` gives me the message :

> type=AVC msg=audit(1493867419.082:61578): avc:  denied  { execute }
>   for  pid=15202 comm="sh" name="phantomjs" dev="xvda1" ino=279975
>   scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
>   tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file
>   permissive=0

what should I do to allow phatomjs by selinux without disabling selinux entirely with `setenforce 0` ?

Comment: You don't want to execute arbitrary code in your `/var/www/`. You should install it to some reasonable directory.

Comment: the ... is the path to my laravel application.